# C syntax understanding issue

Tags: c

I have a piece of code which says

```
pointer = &arbitarystruct

pointer->x1
*pointer->x2
```

Is it the same expression or do x1/x2 belong to two different structs.

Comment: I don't understand the question.

Comment: What do you mean by "Is it the same expression?".  No, x1 and x2 are both members/fields of the same struct.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [ask] page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: hm I think content of question got changed bit due to edit..; I think initially it was just multiplication of two integers (within struct)?

Comment: Your question is not quite clear. If you want to know whether  `pointer->x1` and `arbitarystruct.x1` are the same member on the same struct "instance", then yes (assuming `arbitarystruct` is not a pointer already) - Your `pointer` variable is pointing to the address of `arbitarystruct `, thus any change to `pointer->x1` also affects `arbitarystruct.x1`.

Comment: "two different structs"   --  Now that I re-read your question, are you asking if a struct copy occurred?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently `arbitrarystruct` is a structure that contains two members named `x1` and `x2`.

`pointer->x1` refers to the `x1` member of `arbitrarystruct` (accessed indirectly via the pointer).

`pointer->x2` refers to the `x2` member of that same struct object.

Apparently the `x2` member is a pointer. `*pointer->x2`, which is equivalent to `*(pointer->x2)` (`->` binds more tightly than `*`) deferences that pointer.

Comment: Assuming x2 is a pointer is a stretch.  It could be true, but I suspect that is not the case.

Comment: @donjuedo If it wasn't true, then the code wouldn't compile.

Comment: Do we know it compiles?  The OP didn't say so.

Comment: @donjuedo start with the assumption that code snippets in questions are valid, unless you're *forced* to believe otherwise.

Comment: No, I won't do that.  The OP shows an idea and asks a question.  That is what I know.  If anything, I see his SO rep is 11, and he's asking a syntax question.  Assuming the code compiles is not really such a given.

Comment: @donjuedo: Well, we know the code in the question *won't* compile because of the missing semicolons. Still, my interpretation is that the question is basically "what do these code snippets mean", or at least that answering that question will give the OP enough information to answer his real question.

Comment: And your answer is a good one, @KeithThompson.  My original point was that the OP could spell out the struct declaration, and confirm you are on the right track.

Answer (score 0):

`*pointer->x2` is `*(pointer->x2)` — that is, it's dereferencing `pointer->x2`, which should itself be a pointer. It doesn't involve `*pointer` at all. If it did, it would be invalid, as `(*pointer)->x2` is invalid.